# Rails database query with conditions from two tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these models:

```
class Post
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :posts
end
```

I want to get the post with the title 'Some Title' by any guest user (i.e. user.role == 'guest').

The title will be unique among guest users, but it is possible that some non-guest user has a post with that title. I'm trying to use the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html) and the [Api](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/find/class), but I can't seem to put the right syntax together.

I hoped it was as simple as `User.where(:role => 'guest').posts.find_by_title('some title')`, but that throws *undefined method `posts' for #ActiveRecord::Relation:0x4e6d380*.

`Post.find_by_title('some title', :conditions => {:users => {:role => 'guest'}, :joins => :users}` throws *PG::Error: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "users".*

Anything with `Post.joins(:users)` throws  *Association named 'users' was not found.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Post.joins(:user) (not :users) on the joins.

Comment: Ah! I see how it works now. Because a post belongs_to just one user, :user should be singular. If I wanted User.joins(:posts), then :posts would be plural because a user has_many posts.

Answer (score 2):

Read about using ActiveRecord method `.joins`, that generates `SQL joins`.

```
User.joins(:posts).where("users.role = ? AND posts.title = ?", 'guest', 'some title')
```